# CSS Grid line 1 starts with a margin but can't figure out why

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Never came across this where the first line in a css grid is not flush with the browser window. Don't know where the gap came from but all the other grids on this page works great. I need a logo to sit closer to the edge of the browser window.

below is my html code and the css that goes along with the html.

```
<menu>
        <asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" runat="server">
            <asp:Image ID="imgLogo" CssClass="Logo" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/LogoOrange.png" />
        </asp:HyperLink>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>About Us</li>
                <li>Services</li>
                <li>Online Estimate</li>
                <li>Contact Us</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="PhoneNumber">
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="" />
        </div>
    </menu>

.Logo {
    height: 80px;
    margin: 5px 25px 0px 5px;
}

menu {
    margin: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 5fr 1fr;
    min-width: 1024px;
}

menu nav {
    grid-column: 2/3;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

menu nav ul {
    margin: 0;
}

menu nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0px 10px;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Browser is adding Padding  to your menu just add padding:0 like so

```
menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 5fr 1fr;
    min-width: 1024px;
}
```

Comment: That did it...thank you. funny enough i have a banner on the same page that doesn't have padding: 0 and does not have that gap. Didn't think it would have made a difference but it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You must remove the display: flex;

```
menu nav {
grid-column: 2/3;
display: block;
align-items: center;
justify-content: flex-end;
```

}